# Why isn't this clojure function executing?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm working through some clojure examples from braveclojure:

http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/

Currently I am trying to execute this

```
(ns turtle (:use clojure.pprint))

(def criticisms {:good "good code:" :bad "bad code:"})

(defn criticize-code
    [[critkey code]]
    `(println (~critkey criticisms) (quote ~code)))

(defmacro code-critic
    [code-evaluations]
    `(do ~@(map criticize-code code-evaluations)))

(println "executed code critic")
(code-critic {:good (+ 1 1) :bad (1 + 1)})
(println "code critic expansion")
(pprint (macroexpand '(code-critic {:good (+ 1 1) :bad (1 + 1)})))

;why isn't this executing?
(println "criticize code expansion")
(criticize-code [:good '(+ 1 1)])
```

Basically, I can verify that criticize-code returns properly formatted code through `println`; but I cannot actually execute it...can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `criticize-code` *is* being invoked. The quasi-quote, `, in the body of the function is a reader macro for syntax-quote, which means the following `println` form, after its trip through the syntax-quote reader, will be returned as data structure rather than executed. The `criticize-code` function is semantically equivalent to

```clj
(defn criticize-code
  [[critkey code]]
  (list 
    'clojure.core/println 
    (list critkey 'turtle/criticisms) 
    (list 'quote code)))
```

If you want to treat the resulting data structure as code at the REPL, you can `eval` it directly.

```clj
turtle=> (criticize-code [:good '(+ 1 1)])
(clojure.core/println (:good turtle/criticisms) (quote (+ 1 1)))
turtle=> (eval (criticize-code [:good '(+ 1 1)]))
good code: (+ 1 1)
nil
```

So why would you want a function that works like this? As a helper to a macro, as here for `code-critic`. Macros deal with code-as-data-as-code. Therefore, if you stick in a helper function at the `as-data` stage, it will need to return its result as data. Otherwise, the code you want to be compiled is just executed at "compile" time with its return value (`println` returns `nil`) compiled instead.